# Redirect on different pages against different buttons (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Here its my view i have 2 buttons one is **save and exit** and other is **save and stay Here**

**View**

```
<button type="submit" name="submit_1"> Submit and Exit</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit_2">save and stay Here</button>
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {


        $data['name']             = $request->input('name');
        $data['adr']            = $request->input('adr');

         $myuser = Data::create($data);
          if(Input::get('submit_1')) {
            return redirect()->route('myuser.index');
        } elseif(Input::get('submit_2')) {
            return redirect()->route('myuser.create');
        }
    }
```

I tried this but its not working for me kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try as:

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit_1'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit_2'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**View**

```
<button type="submit" name="submit_1" value="submit_1"> Submit and Exit</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit_2" value="submit_2">save and stay Here</button>
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->get('submit_1') == "submit_1") {
            return redirect()->route('myuser.index');
        } else if($request->get('submit_2') == "submit_2") {
            return redirect()->route('myuser.create');            
        }
    }
```